# How to change jumps (make smoother) of adjusting volume level on notebook? Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, shortcut-keys, volume-control

When I use hotkeys in my notebook to adjust the volume level the level jumps too far from the previous position. Here are only 16 positions 9plus a few for bolstered amp).
Can I change jumps to, say, 25 or more positions to make the volume adjustment much smoother, so every time on pressing the hotkey I will jump, say, on 3-5% of the volume up/down?

*Ubuntu 22.04 x64.*

Thank you in advance.